# "OOPS" kernel message when unloading a module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

Sometimes I receive the flollowing logs from kernel when trying to unload a module using `delete_module` system call:

```
static inline int delete_module(const char *name, int flags)
{
    return syscall(__NR_delete_module, name, flags);
}
```

From the backtrace, the kernel is trying to find a kernfs_node by name and remove it. But the name is NULL in this case. What could be the root cause of such random problem ?

```
[[ 135.142426] st_asm330lhh_spi spi2.0: Removing device 0
[[ 135.143021] st_asm330lhh_spi spi2.0: Removing device 1
[[ 135.145053] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 11ffe6ff
[[ 135.145072] pgd = d75a4000
[[ 135.145082] [11ffe6ff] *pgd=00000000
[[ 135.145097] Internal error: Oops: 5 [#1] PREEMPT ARM
[[ 135.145114] Modules linked in: st_asm330lhh(-) gpio50 [last unloaded: st_asm330lhh]
[[ 135.145139] CPU: 0 PID: 2361 Comm: lifecyclemgr Not tainted 3.18.48 #4
[[ 135.145152] task: cc93b900 ti: cc96c000 task.ti: cc96c000
[[ 135.145170] PC is at strlen+0x4/0x24
[[ 135.145187] LR is at kernfs_name_hash+0x10/0x6c
[[ 135.145201] pc : [<c01f4698>] lr : [<c012e5f0>] psr: 60010013
[[ 135.145201] sp : cc96def8 ip : 00000000 fp : b1bfe48c
[[ 135.145215] r10: 00000000 r9 : cc96c000 r8 : 00000800
[[ 135.145227] r7 : bf0060d0 r6 : 11ffe6ff r5 : 00000000 r4 : 11ffe6ff
[[ 135.145239] r3 : 11ffe6ff r2 : 00000000 r1 : 00000000 r0 : 11ffe6ff
[[ 135.145252] Flags: nZCv IRQs on FIQs on Mode SVC_32 ISA ARM Segment none
[[ 135.145265] Control: 10c53c7d Table: 975a4059 DAC: 00000051
[[ 135.145277] Process lifecyclemgr (pid: 2361, stack limit = 0xcc96c208)
[[ 135.145289] Stack: (0xcc96def8 to 0xcc96e000)
[[ 135.145303] dee0: cc952b50 00000000
[[ 135.145321] df00: 11ffe6ff c012efc8 cc952870 11ffe6ff 00000000 11ffe6ff cc952870 00000000
[[ 135.145339] df20: bf0060d0 c012fd84 bf006088 00000000 cc887c00 c006d678 00000000 bf006088
[[ 135.145357] df40: c0d21008 60010013 00000800 c006d7fc 615f7473 33336d73 68686c30 00000000
[[ 135.145375] df60: 00000000 00000000 cc93b900 00000000 cc93b900 00000000 c0dcd3b8 cc96dfb0
[[ 135.145393] df80: b1bfe494 c0033d14 0096c000 29427fd7 4fe52e18 b1bfe4ac 4fe48a54 00000081
[[ 135.145411] dfa0: c000e624 c000e460 4fe52e18 b1bfe4ac 4fe52e18 00000800 00000000 00000800
[[ 135.145430] dfc0: 4fe52e18 b1bfe4ac 4fe48a54 00000081 002179bc 001c9790 0bebc200 b1bfe48c
[[ 135.145448] dfe0: b1bfe480 b1bfe470 4fe48914 4fafce30 60010010 4fe52e18 e594102c e2840024
[[ 135.145476] [<c01f4698>] (strlen) from [<c012e5f0>] (kernfs_name_hash+0x10/0x6c)
[[ 135.145500] [<c012e5f0>] (kernfs_name_hash) from [<c012efc8>] (kernfs_find_ns+0x70/0xd8)
[[ 135.145524] [<c012efc8>] (kernfs_find_ns) from [<c012fd84>] (kernfs_remove_by_name_ns+0x48/0x78)
[[ 135.145548] [<c012fd84>] (kernfs_remove_by_name_ns) from [<c006d678>] (free_module+0x184/0x1c4)
[[ 135.145569] [<c006d678>] (free_module) from [<c006d7fc>] (SyS_delete_module+0x144/0x1dc)
[[ 135.145591] [<c006d7fc>] (SyS_delete_module) from [<c000e460>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x44)
[[ 135.145609] Code: 1afffff9 e12fff1e c077e998 e1a03000 (e5d32000)
[[ 135.145622] ---[ end trace 7e807feb82cc2ca5 ]---
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Unix & Linux SE!

When a module is unloaded, it needs to free any system resources it has allocated for its operations.

Perhaps the module you're unloading has a bug in it, causing the module unloading process to call `kernfs_remove_by_name_ns()` with a NULL instead of a valid parameter when the module is being unloaded?

A quick glance through the functions referred to in the backtrace indicates the problem is probably the second parameter of `kernfs_remove_by_name_ns()` being NULL.

Looking at [the source code of `free_module()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/module.c#L2127), the first things referring to the module's resources by name would be based on the `name` member in the module's `struct module` - if that's already NULL for some reason when the module is being removed, that Oops would be expected.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. But I don't think the issue is related to the module itself, because the same behavior was seen with other modules from different providers/types ..

Comment: There is an `Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 11ffe6ff` before the oops, so the system state may have been corrupted at some earlier point. Or if you are making several `delete_module()` syscalls quickly one after another, you may have discovered a race condition in the module unloading sequence. You mention "modules from different providers/types" - what exactly are these modules? Any common factors?

Comment: Test done by adding a delay of 1 sec between the occurences of delete_module(). But the issue is seen. 
Example of modules used: st_asm330lhh_spi, gpio50.

Comment: Now, we are trying to add a check of busy state as implemented in "rmmod" source code: https://github.com/vadmium/module-init-tools/blob/master/rmmod.c